# Creating a custom theme for Material Design in Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I know you can create custom primary and accent colors (as discussed here: [How make MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit Custom Color Theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101956/how-make-materialdesigninxamltoolkit-custom-color-theme)), but is there any support for changing or adding additional themes? For instance there is already a Light and Dark theme, and we are looking to build more of a light grey theme as well.

Is there any guides on how to do this, and can it be done outside of the MaterialDesign library, or does it have to be done in the same library as the original two?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used that one particularly but I'd assume you could create your own theme (I'd probably start by copying/editing an existing one) and then just include it in the `MerdedDictionaries` in your app.xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you have provided discusses the core palette.  You can also create your own Light/Dark variations:

- Create your own MyLightGrey.xaml ResourceDictionary.
- Add all brushes from https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/550abb1ef2b629c9f1944c1125683d42ba5e63f6/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml and customise accordingly
- When setting up your App.XAML, just include your new ResourceDictionary instead of the standard .Light/.Dark.xaml